# $Q$ parabolic in $P$, $P$ parabolic in $G$ implies $Q$ parabolic in $G$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I am a bit confused on the proof of this lemma.  $G$ is a linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$.  A closed subgroup $P$ of $G$ is called *parabolic* if the quotient variety $G/P$ is complete.

[image]

First, where is 5.3.2 (i) used?  (This says if $\varphi: X \rightarrow Y$ is an equivariant map of homogeneous $G$-spaces, then $X \times Z \rightarrow Y \times Z$ is an open map for any variety $Z$.)  It seems to me that you just take an $E \subseteq G/Q \times X$ closed, then its preimage $A$ in $G \times X$ is a closed set with the property that $(g,x) \in A \Rightarrow (gQ,x) \in A$, and the projection of $A$ onto $X$ is the same as the projection of $E$.

Next, how is the completeness of $P/Q$ being used?  What does this have to do with the closed set $\alpha^{-1}A \subseteq P \times G \times X$?  Finally, how is the completeness of $G/P$ being used?

Comment: If I am not wrong: the stament 5.3.2 (i) is applied to the equivariant map $\pi\times Id_X:G\times X\to G_{\displaystyle/Q}\times X$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection of $G$ on $G_{\displaystyle/Q}$. Just a pair of questions: are we working in the scheme setting?, what is your reference book?

Comment: We are just working with varieties, so $G \times X$ is really the cartesian product.  I'm using *Linear Algebraic Groups* by T.A. Springer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one needs to use 5.3.2(i) here.

Completeness of $P/Q$ is used to to show that the projection of $\alpha^{-1}(A)$ onto $G\times X$ is closed. Completeness of $G/P$ is used after that, in a similar way. This is worked out in nice detail in [these notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~herzig/lin-alg-groups17-seaton-notes.pdf) of Herzig, where it is proposition 117.